# vim: delete the first 2 spaces for multiple lines

Tags: vim

What's the easiest way to delete the first 2 spaces for each line using VIM? Basically it's repeating "2x" for each line.

Clarification: here the assumption is the first 2 characters are spaces. So the question is about doing indentation for multiple lines together.

Comment: Is it specifically white space, or the first two characters regardless of what they are?

Comment: It's the first two characters. Assuming the first two characters are spaces.

Comment: I've shown a way to do it via search and replace in the ex editor mode. One way guarantees that it will only do it for lines beginning with two spaces (and only remove two spaces). The other just guts the first two characters regardless of what they are.

Comment: Vim questions are not off topic on SO (check discussions on meta, and ... SO FAQ). Moreover indentation **is** relevant to development...

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Some more options. You can decided which is the "easiest way".

**Remove the first 2 characters of every line:**

```
:%normal 2x
```

**Remove first 2 characters of every line, only if they're spaces:**

```
:%s/^  /
```

Note that the last slash is optional, and is only here so that you can see the two spaces. Without the slash, it's only 7 characters, including the `:`.

**Move indentation to left for every line:**

```
:%normal <<
```

Comment: I love that there are 30 different ways to do something in Vim. Questions like these bring up things you never knew about. I had no idea about the %normal.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the last dash. That is helpful.

Comment: I'll add that the `%` sign simply means "execute this command for each line in the document, not just the current line". I think. Can't find much documentation about it.

Answer (score 137):

1. Enter visual block mode with `Ctrl-V` (or `Ctrl-Q` if you use `Ctrl-V` for paste);
2. Select the area to delete with the arrows;
3. Then press `d` to delete the selected area.
4. Press `Esc`

Comment: ctrl-v
to select which characters to remove and then 
    d
for the cut.

Comment: This doesn't work in all vim's I use, but for the ones that it does work it's very convenient and it's nice to be able to visualize the area you're deleting before you actually do it.

Comment: Different default binding for visual block mode perhaps?  Maybe a diff between older unix distribution VI (as opposed to VIM).

Comment: This is probably the easiest and most sensible answer.

Answer (score 15):

You could also use a search and replace (in the ex editor, accessed via the <kbd>:</kbd> character):

Remove first two characters no matter what:

```
%s/^.\{2}//
```

Remove first two white space characters (must be at the beginning and both must be whitespace... any line not matching that criteria will be skipped):

```
%s/^\s\{2}//
```

Comment: The /g at the end is superfluous. You're only doing one match per line.

Comment: imo this is a great solution

Answer (score 7):

Assuming a `shiftwidth=2`, then using shift with a range of `%`

```
:%<
```

Answer (score 4):

Two spaces, or two characters?  (`2x` does the latter.)

```
:[range]s/^  //
```

deletes two blanks at the beginning of each line; use `%` (equivalent to `1,$`) as `[range]` do to this for the entire file.

```
:[range]s/^..//
```

deletes the first two characters of each line, whatever they are.  (Note that it deletes two *characters*, not necessarily two *columns*; a tab character counts as one character).

If what you're really doing is changing indentation, you can use the `<` command to decrease it, or the `>` command to increase it.  Set `shiftwidth` to control how far it shifts, e.g.

```
:set shiftwidth=2
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd try one of two approaches:

1. Do column editing on the block to delete using `Ctrl+V` (often mapped to `Ctrl+Q`).
2. Record a macro on the first row using `q1` (or any other number/letter you want to denote the recording register), then replay that macro multiple times using `@1` (to use my previous example. Even better, use a preceding number to tell it how many times to run - `10@1` to run that macro 10 times, for example. It does, however, depends on what you recorded - make sure to rewind the cursor `0` or drop one line `j`, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 3):

I'd also add: learn how to configure indentation for vim. Then a simple `gg=G` will do the trick.