# Remove 8 extra spaces in front of each line for all 800 lines

Tags: linux, bash, vi

I have 800 lines of code in the vi editor. I have 8 extra spaces in front of every line. How can I remove 8 spaces for all 800 lines at a time?

Please note some lines are

```
abc
  dbc
   hfs
```

but in front of everyline there are 8 spaces and I need only those 8 spaces to be deleted and the remaining spaces must remain the same.

Comment: You can adapt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961705/vim-delete-the-first-2-spaces-for-multiple-lines to 8 spaces, no?

Comment: Or a pure bash solution of `while IFS= read -r line; do echo ${line:8}; done < file.txt > newfile.txt`

Comment: Or in Vim directly, simply `:1,$s/^        //` (8-spaces between `^......./`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1,$ s/^        //g` in vi. There are 8 spaces after the `^` and before the `/`.

Comment: As a +1: using `%` is the equivalent of `1,$`.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I'm not a vimmer really. More of an Emacs person. These are just things that I remember from my early days with vi.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/^ \{8\}//' file.txt
```

The replacement pattern, `s/^ \{8\}//`, will substitute 8 spaces at the start of line(s) with null.

As a side note, if you are looking to replace all horizontal whitespaces (in your `locale`), not just space, use the character class `[:blank:]`:

```
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]\{8\}//' file.txt
```

---

Similarly `awk` with the `sub()` function:

```
awk 'sub("^ {8}", "") 1' file.txt
awk 'sub("^[[:blank:]]{8}", "") 1' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sed 's/ *$//' file
```

This will remove all the spaces which is at the end of each line.

Comment: the spaces are before each line

Comment: there are 8 extra spaces before each line for all 800 lines of code . i wanted to remove only 8 spaces before each line for all 800 lines of code at a time . can you please help ?