# VIM: delete the first x non-space characters for multiple lines with uneven indentation

Tags: vim

With consistent indentation, I understand how to do this per [vim: delete the first 2 spaces for multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961705/vim-delete-the-first-2-spaces-for-multiple-lines)

What if we have inconsistent indentation?

Example input:

```
#for i in range(5):
  #print(i)
```

Example output:

```
for i in range(5):
  print(i)
```

I've tried using visual-block mode + '6' to go to the first character in the line, but '6' doesn't jump to the first non-white character in a line block like it does in normal mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of ways. The simplest is probably Visual: <kbd>V</kbd> (select) <kbd>:</kbd> `norm _x` <kbd>CR</kbd> (for each line in visual range, go to first non-indent character and delete it). `:help V`; `:help :normal-range`; `:help _`; `:help x`

However... this should be a non-issue. I encourage you to comment with `#` being on the same column:

```
# for i in range(5):
#   print(i)
```

Better yet, grab Tim Pope's [Commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) plugin, which comments and uncomments in many languages (including Python) painlessly.

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thank you!  I'll try commenting at the beginning of the line from now on.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use substitution command with a regex.

```
:%s/\(^\s*\)\S/\1/
```

`%s` runs the substitution across the whole file
`\(^\s*\)` groups the beginning of the line and the optional white-space characters
`\S` match the first non-whitespace character - you can add more of these if you want to delete 3
`\1` make the replacement the first group